# How I can querying a firestore request in r?

Tags: r, google-cloud-firestore, httr

I have some functions to make a request in firestore and extract some data:

```
sign.up <- function(email, password, api_key) {
  library(jsonlite)
  library(httr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  #https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-create-email-password
  r <- POST(paste0("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=", api_key),
            add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
            body = toJSON(list(email = email, password = password, returnSecureToken = TRUE),auto_unbox=TRUE))
  return(content(r))
}

sign.in <- function(email, password, api_key) {
  library(jsonlite)
  library(httr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  #https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password
  r <- POST(paste0("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=", api_key),
            add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
            body = toJSON(list(email = email, password = password, returnSecureToken = TRUE),auto_unbox=TRUE))
  return(content(r))
}

read.db <- function(db_endpoint, auth_token) {
  library(jsonlite)
  library(httr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  r <- GET(sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", db_endpoint),
           add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json",
                       "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)))
  return(r)
}

my_auth_info<-sign.in(
    "mymail@mail.com",
    "password",
    "XXXXXXXXXXtoken"
  )

json<-
    read.db(
      "projects/partrunner-prod/databases/(default)/documents/driver_lead?pageSize=300",
      my_auth_info$idToken
    )
  
  json <-
    fromJSON(content(json,"text"))
```

but the collection is too big and I want to filter the data considering a field called phone_country_code="mx"

how I can pass a `where` condition into the body of the request? im a bit confused about the logic on this part

Comment: If you had explained a bit with comments about what sorts of results are expected with `firestone` then we might be able to offer better advice. Assuming the GET call returns an R dataframe object then perhaps something like `return( r %>% filter(phone_country_code=="mx") )`? Or perhaps `filter( json  ,phone_country_code=="mx") )`